Response body truncated. 504 timeout Google cloud
I have two services implemented on Cloud Run. In the first service, called 'A', I'm making a request to the second service, called 'B'. When I make a specific call, such as https://A/revisions/463fc2ce-9140-47f7-8294-240a5640a49b/pages, it fails with the following error on the side of service 'A': 504 errors with the message 'The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout'. Looking at the logs of client 'B', I noticed a warning message: Response body truncated. This usually means that the request timed out or that the application exited before finishing the response.
Why is this happening with that specific request when I call it x times, but if I call https://A/revisions/543fc2ce-9140-47f7-8294-240a5640a49b/pages x times, it doesn't happen?
This is the configuration that I have in the yaml in both services:
resource_requests:
cpu: 1
memory: 512
resource_limits:
cpu: 1
memory: 512
min_scale: 1
max_scale: 100
cloud_run_gen: gen2
ports:
name: http1
port: 8080
startup_cpu_boost: true
cpu_always_allocated: true

I'm using Quarkus 2.16.12 with reactive, Java 17 and MongoDB
The error occurs when returning the response from service (B) to service (A)

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue.

If your service is processing long requests, you can increase the request timeout. If your service doesn't return a response within the time specified, the request ends and the service returns an HTTP 504 error, as documented in the container runtime contract.
To troubleshoot this issue, try one or more of the following steps mentioned in  Google's troubleshooting documentation. I would also suggest you to check  this documentation on Cloud Run responds with an HTTP 504 Gateway timeout error.
If you are still facing the issue consider contacting  Google Cloud Support to further investigate the problem or file a bug through the Google Cloud issue tracker.
